# Vb .net error "input string was not in a correct format"

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I dont know what is wrong with my code. please see below screenshot

[image]

can any one tell what is the issue? I am using visual studio 2010 coupled with Ms SQL 2008

Comment: You are missing '}' closing at "{3}".

Comment: thanks now i got this error "Sqlexception was unhandled" Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id', table 'NASL.dbo.Employee'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: You should be using parameterized queries, not just relying on good old user input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing '}' closing at "{3}"

I am thinking that id column would be an auto incrementing value.

If not then you need to set this, or else if you have a non-nullable column, with no default value, if you provide no value it will throws an error.

To set up auto-increment in SQL Server Management Studio:

Step-1:Open your table in Design mode
Step-2:Select your column and go to Column Properties
Step-3:Under Indentity Specification, set Is Identity=Yes and Indentity Increment=1

Comment: I was just about to shoot myself in the head until I found this tutorial

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

This will cover the proper way to insert the Data using `Parameterized Queries`:

```
Dim cmd as new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.Employee(Fullname, Position, EmployeeNumber, Salary) Values (@Name, @Position, @Number, @Salary)", conn)
cmd.parameters.addWithValue("@Name", txtFullName.Text)
cmd.parameters.addWithValue("@Position", txtPosition.Text)
cmd.parameters.addWithValue("@EmployeeNumber", Integer.Parse(txtEmployeeNumber.Text))  'Assuming You have employee number in integer
cmd.parameters.addWithValue("@Salary", Integer.Parse(txtSalary.Text)) 'Assuming You have employee number in integer

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Feel free to ask if you have any doubts. And you will not get the above error unless you have different datatypes set in database.

Answer (score -1):

You have not specified id column in query.

OR mark id column as identity in employee table

Comment: If the `ID` column is specified as `Primary` and `Auto Increment`, then there's no need to specify `ID` column in query